# How I Render A Html/JavaScript In Grails Controller?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a controller code like this :

```
def test23() {
        //params.id23 is been passed via ajax calls
        def find = User.findByUsernameLike("${params.id23}")
        println find
        render """<script type="text/javascript"> alert("hi"); </script>""" 
    }
```

This code is called using jquery's `ajax` method. Well, it works well, that is , I get output printed on my console, but the `render` part is not working (I'm not getting the `alert`).

What I done is correct? Or anything else need to be passed to render those scripts?

Comment: *shudder*... view code in the controller ;-)  -- As a more helpful comment, you should really consider not doing this in the controller, and moving it into the view.  So the AJAX requests a value, receives a Json object containing 'hi' and then calls `alert` or something. Or look at templating frameworks in javascript...  It really depends what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @tim_yates : I just want to know whether that works, wont put in my code though. But even though render should show me a alert, it doesn't that's why asked here :)

Comment: @tim_yates: thanks for that advice. I need to just append some data's to the DOM (i.e to some `id` elements so that user can see it), after user selecting a value from drop-down list box :)

Comment: in that situation, I'd [render a map `as JSON`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#xmlAndJSON), and deal with attaching it to the DOM client-side

Comment: @tim_yates: I have a quick question, I heard of JSON, but haven't tried it. Lets say I want attach a div to DOM, div has only one line content in it. In that case to, using a JSON matters?

Comment: No, but it saves you a pain in the backside when it has 2 lines later on...

Comment: @tim_yates : Thanks a lot for your advice and suggestions... Have a groovy day sir.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this instead:

```
render text: """<script type="text/javascript"> alert("hi"); </script>""",
        contentType: 'js'
```

or possibly:

```
render text: """<script type="text/javascript"> alert("hi"); </script>""", 
        contentType: 'text/javascript'
```

Comment: I am with Tim on this, returning script tag is not very MVCish. You should definitely return JSON or an html fragment from a template.